# Where is Featured Image code stored in WP?

Tags: uploads, wp-filesystem

Well, I'm looking for source code of these two small containers (PHP backend, HTML frontend & JS used to attach the image):

[image: Featured Image]

I want to build a theme option based on Featured Image code, but I'm not able to find it. I'm pretty sure it is somewhere in wp-admin directory, but I've spent loong time there and found nothing.

Any clues?

Comment: search for `set-post-thumbnail`- media-upload.php, set-post-thumbnail.js

Comment: +1 for the "most porn pic posted on WPSE"! Nice way to get answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Markup of that metabox is generated by [`_wp_post_thumbnail_html()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_wp_post_thumbnail_html) function, contained in [`wp-admin/includes/post.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-admin/includes/post.php#L1215).

Comment: you are the man! But I'm starring at that function and I'm still unable to reconstruct the ajax-way image appears, anyways thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Some handy links for you:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_post_thumbnail

Those are useful if you're wanting to display or act differently in the theme, based on the featured image.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example to have the **Featured image meta box** display and work *outside the `wp-admin/post.php` page context* (since WordPress 4.6, see [`wp-admin/includes/post.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.6/src/wp-admin/includes/post.php)), which is one of the possible reason why you might want to know where is the code stored:

```
/**
 * Featured image metabox
 *
 * @uses _wp_post_thumbnail_html
 *
 * @param int    $post_id   Post ID.
 * @param string $post_type Post type.
 */
function featured_image_metabox( $post_id, $post_type ) {

    // @see edit-form-advanced.php
    $thumbnail_support = current_theme_supports( 'post-thumbnails', $post_type ) && post_type_supports( $post_type, 'thumbnail' );

    if ( ! $thumbnail_support ||
        ! current_user_can( 'upload_files' ) ) {

        return;
    }

    // All meta boxes should be defined and added before the first do_meta_boxes() call (or potentially during the do_meta_boxes action).
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php';

    if ( ! $post_id ) {
        // New post.
        $post = get_default_post_to_edit( $post_type, true );

        // Fix PHP error. Add filter so get_post( $post ) returns our post!
        $post->filter = 'raw';
    } else {
        $post = get_post( $post_id );
    }

    $thumbnail_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_thumbnail_id', true );

    if ( ! $thumbnail_id ) {

        $thumbnail_id = -1;
    }

    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object( $post_type );

    $title = $post_type_object->labels->featured_image;
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery( document ).ready(function( e ) {
            wp.media.view.settings.post.id = <?php echo json_encode( $post->ID ); ?>;
            wp.media.view.settings.post.featuredImageId = <?php echo json_encode( $thumbnail_id ); ?>;
            wp.media.view.settings.post.nonce = <?php echo json_encode( wp_create_nonce( 'update-post_' . $post->ID ) ); ?>;
        });
    </script>
    <div id="poststuff" style="min-width: 320px;">
        <div id="postimagediv" class="postbox">
            <h2 class='hndle'><span><?php echo esc_html( $title ); ?></span></h2>
            <div class="inside">
            <?php
                echo _wp_post_thumbnail_html( $thumbnail_id, $post );
            ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

[image: Working example (Sensei LMS course wizard), in the wp-admin, but outside the post context]

Comment: How does this answer the question asked?

Comment: Well, this is not answering to where is the code located, but to how to reuse it outside current post context.